# Vert.x Java for multiplayer game

Tags: java, vert.x, multiplayer, vertx-eventbus, real-time-multiplayer

I want make a simple quiz game with a lobby system. I have some doubts about the architecture to use in my system, my idea was to use a central server to manage the lobbies and every time a lobby is created, instantiate a new `LobbyVerticle`, the communication between client and server was entrusted to the event `Vert.x` bus. The game must respect scalability and distribution.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x does not implement a strict actor model, therefore, you won't have actor specific features like mailboxes and persistent actors, with that said, I would opt for an approach where you have `N` lobby verticles instances where `n = 2 * CPUs`, each of the verticles can handle any existing lobby, I would then share lobby state using clustered shared-data-api (requires cluster manager like `hz`) if persistence is required you could write a verticle that persists data in a write-behind fashion.

If you want to go for an actor-oriented approach choose another tool like light bend `akka`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for the client side i want use a web page, so i found on vertx doc that i can use SockJs for the communication. the approach where i create a event bus in each Verticle for comunicate with client is good?